# How to solve the error use of deleted function 'QFile::QFile(const QFile&)' on qt4?

Tags: c++, qt

Could someone help me, I am getting this deleted function error in an open source project I'm trying to compile. I'm new on C++ projects.

stacktrace:

> ```
> Emmeth\src\qEmmeth\mainwindow.cpp:80: error: use of deleted function 'QFile::QFile(const QFile&)'
> ..\qEmmeth\mainwindow.cpp: In member function 'void MainWindow::open()':
> ..\qEmmeth\mainwindow.cpp:80:38: error: use of deleted function 'QFile::QFile(const QFile&)'
> MainWindow::loadFile(fileName);
> ^
> ```

```
void MainWindow::open()
{
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Load file"), "../../", tr("Emmeth Files (.emt);; XML Files (.xml);; PDF Files (.pdf);; TXT Files (.txt)"));

if(!fileName.isEmpty()){
    QFile file(fileName);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Error"), tr("Could not open file"));
        return;
    }
    qDebug() << "Open:"  + fileName;
    MainWindow::loadFile(fileName);
}
}
```

Thanks to the answers, the implementation of loadfile is:

```
void MainWindow::loadFile(QFile fileName)
{
    //get File ending info
    QFileInfo fi(fileName);
    QString base   = fi.completeBaseName(); //Filename without memory address
    QString ending = fi.completeSuffix();  //only Ending
    //qDebug() << fi(fileName);
    qDebug() << "base: " + base;
    qDebug() << "ending: " + ending;

    //open according to the ending
    //TODO change to switch
    if(ending == "pdf"){ //load reader classes and render by the reader.
        //QImage pdfImage = new QImage();
        QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Error"), tr("Pdf not implemented yet."));
        // QImage pdfImage = pdfReader::load(fileName.fileName());
    }
    if(ending == "xml"){
        //opening xml file
        qDebug() << "reading xml file.";
        statusBar()->showMessage("opening document", 3000);
        qDebug() << fileName.fileName();
        //read the content and more
        xmlReader   *reader  = new xmlReader();
        QString     result   = reader->load(fileName.fileName());
        QStringList Verses   = reader->readChapterVerses(fileName.fileName());
        QString     bookName = reader->readBookTitle(fileName.fileName());

        //build UI
        createMdiArea(result);
        MainWindow::getBookNames();

        //add book name, chapter and verses
        qDebug() << cmbBook->findText(bookName);
        cmbBook->setCurrentIndex(cmbBook->findText(bookName));
        //cmbBook->addItem(bookName);
        for(int i = 1; i <= Verses.count(); i++){
            cmbChapter->addItem(QString::number(i));
        }
        for(int i = 1; i <= Verses[0].toInt(); i++){
            cmbVerse->addItem(QString::number(i));
        }

    }
```

This code it's a little confusing, in the loadfile function it needs a file as parameter but in the changebook above, it needs a QString.

Chagebook function below:

```
void MainWindow::changeBook(){
    QString bookName = cmbBook->currentText();
    //check if number is at the beginning.
    if(!bookName.isEmpty()){
        if(bookName.at(1) == ("1" || "2")){
            QString number = bookName.at(1);
            bookName.remove(0,2);
            bookName.append(" ");
            bookName.append(number);
        }
        bookName.replace(" ", "_");
        bookName.append(".xml");
        //open file at in the right directory
        qDebug() << "Path: " << path.first();
        QString libraryPath = path.first();
        libraryPath.append("/library/bibles/tanach-xml/");
        QDir pathLibrary = libraryPath;
        qDebug() << "libraryPath:" << libraryPath;
        if(pathLibrary.exists())
        {
            //ApplicationPath/library/bibles/Translation/Name[_Number].xml
            QString fileName = QString(libraryPath);
            fileName.append(bookName);
            QFile file(fileName);
            loadFile(file);
        }else{
            qDebug() << "Cannot open path: " + QString(pathLibrary.path());
        }
    }else{
        qDebug() << "Error reading book name.";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe the code shown can produce this error. Do you have `MainWindow::loadFile(file)` in the actual code you are trying to compile? What's the declaration of `MainWindow::loadFile`?

Comment: Thanks guys, the implementation of loadfile is above.

Comment: change the call  from `MainWindow::loadFile(fileName);` to `MainWindow::loadFile(file);`

Comment: The same error raised for MainWindow::loadFile(file); RichardCritten

Comment: I guess `QFile`  is not copyable or moveable then; so change `void MainWindow::loadFile(QFile fileName)` to `void MainWindow::loadFile(QFile & fileName)` as well.

Comment: It's not clear why `loadFile` takes a `QFile` parameter, and not a `QString`. All it uses the parameter for is the file name, it doesn't actually use any functionalty of `QFile`. And the name of the parameter, `fileName`, also suggests that the author probably meant to take a string.

Comment: Yes @IgorTandetnik, i have thinkink that too. After see the Richard Critten i have thinkink that. This code it's a little confuse  see in the loadfile function, it needs realy a file as param but in the changebook above, it needs a QString. Weel, i still learn, compile and improve the software. I'm enjoy the challenge but i'm new in the c++. I'm a C# and Delphi developer of only thre years of experience.

Comment: It's works fine now Thanks guys!!! I change the changebook function like above. And the others changes. I will set above the final code.